# Android Studio app.gradle error in appcompat

Tags: gradle

Dependencies using groupId com.android.support and androidx.* can not be combined but found

> `IdeMavenCoordinates{myGroupId='com.android.support',
>   myArtifactId='support-vector-drawable', myVersion='26.1.0',
>   myPacking='aar', myClassifier='null'}`and
>   `IdeMavenCoordinates{myGroupId='androidx.asynclayoutinflater',
>   myArtifactId='asynclayoutinflater', myVersion='1.0.0',
>   myPacking='aar', myClassifier='null'}`

incompatible dependencies

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a conflict between the deprecated appcompat library and Firebase

Solved the same issue by migrating the old and deprecated appcompat support library to the new `androidx`. Official docs here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same error for a few days and only achieve success after migrating all project to SDK 28.

Update all project dependencies

***File* -> *Project Structure***

[image]

[image]

> With Android Studio 3.2 and higher, go to menu ***Refactor* -> *Migrate to
> AndroidX***

[image]

It's worth mentioning without Migrating to AndroidX, the Gradle has been synced successfully, but when running the project I've got this error

> ***Manifest merger failed: Attribute application@appComponentFactory...***